# How to return correct model after complex joins on a relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, models

Given the database & model structure:

A *suburb* **belongs to many custom areas**

```
suburbs:
   - id
   - name
```

A *custom* **belongs to many suburbs**

```
custom_areas:
    - id
    - name

custom_area_suburbs:
    - custom_area_id
    - suburb_id
```

A *public* **holiday belongs to a custom area**

```
public_holidays:
    - id
    - date
    - custom_area_id
```

Given that I have a $suburb, I'm trying to get a collection of all of it's public holidays.

The follow returns the correct data **however** it returns a collection of custom areas with public holiday data, I'm trying to return **just** a collection of public holidays.

Here's the code that almost works:

```
$suburb->customAreas()
            ->join('public_holidays', 'custom_areas.id','=','public_holidays.custom_area_id')
            ->select('custom_areas.*','public_holidays.*')
            ->get();
```

// Returns a collection of *CustomArea*, but with the public holiday data, it should just be a collection of *PublicHolidays*

Comment: I have relationships already:
A suburb belongs to many custom areas, 
A custom area belongs to many suburbs, 
A public holiday belongs to a custom area.

Is there another relationship I can add to simplify? Cheers :)

Comment: Can you put your Models here ? With the relationships

Comment: It's a collection of `CustomArea` models, because you're using the relationship from which to build the query.

Comment: Build a query using the PublicHolidays model and you'll get objects of this class as a result.